# Where can I download debian-test.iso?

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I'm new to debian, I don't know much about the distribution of debian, want to try it on my laptop.

As far as I know, the debian testing version is rolling 'release' and kind of stable, and not so old as stable version. I want to try this version. But I didn't know well about the difference among these versions.

http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage

'Weekly builds of installer images'

'Weekly builds of live images'

'Daily builds of installer images'

'stretch-alpha5'

Currently I only know the daily build version is unstable/sid version, which I don't want. But what's the difference between weekly build and stretch-alpha5 ? And I prefer gnome desktop, I didn't see any gnome-livecd among these isos. Which one should I choose ? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [image catalog](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/):

> Alpha/Beta/Release Candidate builds of Debian Installer for Stretch
>
> - [Alpha 5](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/stretch_di_alpha5/) is most recent - a full set of installer images for all architectures
>
> Regular builds of testing / (what will be Stretch)
>
> - [Daily builds of installer images](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/daily-builds/) for all architectures (small CDs only)
> - [Weekly builds of installer images](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/weekly-builds/) for all architectures (some CDs, full sets of DVDs and BDs)
> - [Weekly builds of live images](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/weekly-live-builds/) for i386 and amd64
> - [Weekly builds of openstack images](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/openstack/testing/) for amd64

Alpha 5 refers to the [`debian-installer`](https://lists.debian.org/debian-boot/2016/01/msg00216.html) release; this is a tested release with release notes and [errata](https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/errata).

The daily and weekly builds also install `testing`, but they are built automatically and there are no guarantees as far as the installer is concerned.

The default desktop on netinst CDs is Gnome; the other images specify which desktop they install (XFCE on the other Alpha 5 image; the weekly live images are available with Cinnamon, Gnome, KDE, LXDE, MATE and XFCE).

The safer bet is to use the netinst Alpha 5 CD.